# Is there a way to capture the event price "label" with Webform CiviCRM?

Tags: civievent, drupal, webform-civicrm, registration

With a default CiviCRM event registration, the fee level has a label that is captured and displayed in participant listings:

[image: participant listing]

When we use Webform CiviCRM as an event registration interface, the amount is captured and displays in the amount column, but the "Fee level" column is simply blank. If we set up the payment field as a dropdown, is there a way to capture the label that is used and display that in participant listings and exports in a similar way for additional context, so we don't have to remember what the dollar figure means (which could be different for different events)?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is another example of this issue?
https://www.drupal.org/node/2840851

Short version - Webform CiviCRM does not provide line item detail to CiviCRM, which only guesses, sometimes wrongly, the details. That issue provides a patch which tries to make smarter guesses.